# Help identify stucco layers on my house

Tags: walls, paint, stucco

I’m looking to redo my stucco, and I’m trying to figure out what each layer of stucco is on my house.

Could someone help explain what each layer of the stucco is in the image, and which layer I need to pressure wash down to?

[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert, but my "as seen on TV" knowledge says you've got: 1) wall board of some sort (at the corner of the opening), 2) scratch coat (lighter grey), 3) skim coat (yellow), 4) possibly a bonding agent in green (it looks very thin), 5) finish coat. Oddly, there's no metal lathe in there, which is what the stucco usually holds on to. I don't have a clue how much you should remove to before adding more. Maybe another picture showing a larger area may help the more knowledgeable folks make a better determination.

Comment: Need to add a picture with a larger section of wall please. It looks like just from the close up you have is all finished stucco with 2 layers of paint and a wrongfully applied coat of something over all of to do something with it. The bigger picture will show what the top layer is doing, for example, is  it is over the whole wall as the finish, or only in places. Then that would lead to the question, what was in the open hole that exposed the yellow and green that is paint? Stucco is never green or yellow, always gray possibly brown